# snprintf crashing my program

Tags: arduino-uno, c++

I have to admit that I can't really use this function.

I'm trying to format some json but it crashing all the time my arduino:

```
char response[300];
tmp = "123";
snprintf(response, 300, "[{Name:'Furnace',Value=%s,Alarm={MinValue=%s,MaxValue=%s}},{Name:'Room',Value=%s,Alarm={MinValue=%s,MaxValue=%s}}]", tmp);
```

How should I use this function properly?

Comment: That's not JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```c
char response[300];
tmp = "123";
snprintf(response, 300,
    "[{Name:'Furnace',Value=%s,Alarm={MinValue=%s,MaxValue=%s}},"
    "{Name:'Room',Value=%s,Alarm={MinValue=%s,MaxValue=%s}}]",
    tmp, tmp, tmp, tmp, tmp, tmp);
```

In other words, you should add, after the format string, as many extra
parameters as there are %s in the format string.

PS: This looks like JSON, but it is not really valid JSON.
The format below should give valid JSON:

```c
"[{\"Name\":\"Furnace\",\"Value\":%s,"
"\"Alarm\":{\"MinValue\":%s,\"MaxValue\":%s}},"
"{\"Name\":\"Room\",\"Value\":%s,"
"\"Alarm\":{\"MinValue\":%s,\"MaxValue\":%s}}]",
```